# Significance of few attributes in ZAP report alert

Tags: security, owasp, zap, websecurity

Could someone explain or provide a reference around understanding of following attributes in ZAP report alert:

1. Instances
2. Reference
3. CWE ID
4. WASC ID
5. Source ID

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Instances

Depending which output your looking at this is either a count of instances where the alert was identified, or a list of the impacted URLs.

> 2. Reference

URLs that point to additional related material.

> 3. CWE ID

The relevant "common weakness enumeration" identifier (https://cwe.mitre.org/)

> 4. WASC ID

The relevant "web application security consortium" identifier (http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246970/Threat%20Classification%20Enumeration%20View)

> 5. Source ID

The identifier of the active or passive scan rule that created the Alert.
1 https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/develop/docs/scanners.md

Further info:

- https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/alerts/
- https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/addalert/